# Faster than xlib

Tags: c++, linux, user-interface

I've searched for lightweight GUIs and found several (e.g. FLTK) but what I really want is a fast library on Linux/Ubuntu. It does not need to be cross-platform. It just has to be fast.

My application is simple. I have a canvas say 800x800 and on it I am:
- drawing 200x200 squares in a grid
- a few strings of text
- some hotspots where a person can press a mouse.

I'm trying to push the frame rate as fast as I can. I've already found sample X11 C++ code.

Is there a faster library than X?

TIA

---

Update: Here is sample code in glut. It looks like I can get one frame in 20ms on my laptop (Sony Vaio  i7-3632QM 2.2Ghz running Ubuntu 12.04). As an aside, it looks like TV "snow" when it runs...

I could not get the equivalent sample to run with Xlib. It keeps terminating with errors similar to:
"XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0" after 86 requests (86 known processed) with 10 events remaining."

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int win_w = 0.0;
int win_h = 0.0;

#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>

void drawGrid(int size)
  {
  const int cellsize = 3;
  const int gridsize = size * cellsize;
  for (int y = 0; y < gridsize; y += cellsize)
    {
    for (int x = 0; x < gridsize; x += cellsize)
      {
      int c = rand() % 100;
      if (c < 33)
        glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
      else if (c < 66)
        glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
      else
        glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

      glRecti(x, y, x + cellsize, y + cellsize);
      }
    }
  }

void display(void)
  {
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glOrtho(0, win_w, 0, win_h, -1, 1);
  glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  glTranslatef(30, 30, 0);
  drawGrid(200);
  glFlush();
  glutSwapBuffers();
  }

void reshape(int w, int h)
  {
  win_w = w;
  win_h = h;
  glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
  }

static int lasttime = 0L;
void idle()
  {
  const int timePerFrame = 19; //ms
  int t = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
  int delay = timePerFrame - (t - lasttime);
  if (delay < 0)
    {
    std::cout << t << "  " << lasttime << "  " << delay << "\n";
    }
  else
    {
    ::usleep(delay * 1000);
    }
  glutPostRedisplay();
  lasttime = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
  }

int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);
  glutInitWindowSize(800, 800);
  glutCreateWindow("test Glut");
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
  glutIdleFunc(idle);
  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Potentially OpenGL. Are you sure it's the toolkit that slowing you down and not your code, or the way you've coded it though?

Comment: x is not a gui library

Comment: mat: No I'm not sure and it's an excellent question. But you can see my choice: I can spend a long time figuring out what's wrong with the xlib code I have and *then* find out there was something simpler, quicker, etc. or I can ask now and spend whatever time it takes to learn the new tool/lib etc.

Comment: Glut is cross-platform. Assuming cross-platform code incurs some overhead, my question is: Is there anything similar to Glut strictly for Ubuntu/Linux?

Answer (score 0):

There are two "X libraries". Good, old Xlib and XCB. XCB should be "faster" as it has modern architecture. If you are not happy with performance of these two, you can avoid them by using the Linux framebuffer directly, or by using the DirectFB (http://www.directfb.org).

However, framebuffer will not run in an X window. So, you really need the simplest possible Xlib or XCB code to create a window for your application, and use GLX to render onto that window's surface.

Finally, the best option for you is SDL I believe. URL: http://www.libsdl.org .